# Angular 8 optional url parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LayoutComponent } from './layouts/layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        loadChildren: './layouts/layout.module#LayoutModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {      /* THIS BELOW BLOCK WORKS */
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './layouts/layout.module#LayoutModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am trying to have 2 different url sets with same set of layouts. so my first url will be like
http://localhost:4200/account - this works fine
http://localhost:4200/20/account - this is my 2nd url and this doesn't work and the error message is

```
core.js:5882 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '20/account'
```

I am not sure where I gone wrong, anyone can help this out?

Comment: out of 2 routes in your code which one is working ?

Comment: @piyushjain updated with comment please check

Comment: @overflow is it correct to assume that by :id you mean account?

Answer (score 0):

you can delete path :':id' and in contractor get parameters:

```
  public constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        injector: Injector
    ) {
        super(injector);
        this.route.params.subscribe((p) => {
            this.stateIdFilter = [Number.parseInt(p.id)];
            if (p.id) {
               this.getData();
            }
        });      }
```

Comment: My approach is not possible? Because It won't be integer, may be string or mixed type